# Cannot add attachment to new RT ticket

Tags: java, rest, rt

I'm currently using RT 4.4.3 in a project and I'm trying to create a new ticket with an attachment, using Java code.

I tried to follow the instructions provided by [this BestPractical resource](https://github.com/bestpractical/rt-extension-rest2) hosted on GitHub and specified in this list of pulls.

The code fragment that tries to perform the operation is the following:

```
PostMethod mPost = new PostMethod(TicketListConstants.SEGNALAZIONI_RTIR_URI + "/ticket");

        mPost.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        mPost.setRequestHeader("Authorization", TicketListConstants.SEGNALAZIONI_RTIR_TOKEN);

        /*String json = ;
        NameValuePair[] data = {
                new NameValuePair("content", json)
        };*/
        UploadPortletRequest uploadRequest = PortalUtil.getUploadPortletRequest(request);
        File file = uploadRequest.getFile("fileName");
        String filename = uploadRequest.getFileName("fileName");

        byte[] filecontent = this.encodeBase64(file);

        mPost.setRequestBody("{ \"Queue\": \"Infosharing\", \"Subject\": \""+subject+"\",\"From\":\""+currentUser.getEmailAddress()+"\",\"To\":\"test@liferay.com\",\"Owner\":\""
                                +currentUser.getEmailAddress()+"\",\"Requestor\":\""+currentUser.getEmailAddress()+"\",\"Content\":\""+description+"\",\"AttachmentsContents\":[{\"FileName\":\""+filename+"\",\"FileType\":\"application/pdf\",\"FileContent\":\""+filecontent+"\"}]}");
        HttpClient cl = new HttpClient();
        String result = "";
        String newId = "";
        try {
            cl.executeMethod(mPost);
            result = mPost.getResponseBodyAsString();

            if (result != null) {
                JSONObject json = null;
                try {
                    json = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject(result);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    _log.error("Error extracting ticket info: "+e.getMessage());
                }
                newId = json.getString("id");
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
            _log.error("Error in searching tickets: "+e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException io) {
            _log.error("Error in searching tickets: "+io.getMessage());
        }
```

So the JSON I'm sending to RT is the following:

```
{ "Queue": "Infosharing", "Subject": "Tutto in uno","From":"test@liferay.com","To":"test@liferay.com","Owner":"test@liferay.com","Requestor":"test@liferay.com","Content":"Aggiungo tutto in un solo passaggio","AttachmentsContents":[{"FileName":"prova.txt","FileType":"plain/text","FileContent":""}]}
```

The problem is that the ticket is correctly created but no attachment is added.

I also tried to perform the same using SOAPUI but no attachment is added to the ticket even if the response is without any error.

Could somebody help me what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT 2019-06-10:** since it seems that, as reported [here](https://metacpan.org/pod/RT::Client::REST::Attachment), at least till the end of December 2018:

> CREATING ATTACHMENTS Currently RT does not allow creating attachments
>   via their API.
>
> See https://rt-wiki.bestpractical.com/wiki/REST#Ticket_Attachment

but it should be possible, as a temporary workaround, to post attachments to ticket's comments, can anybody help finding a solution to this problem?

Comment: How can we check, do you have any url ?

Comment: It is in the very first line: somehow http://<our_RT_SERVER_IP>/REST/2.0/ticket

Comment: Can you check whether RT provided any Swagger details about how to create a ticket with attachment ?

Comment: Just updated question.

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to create a ticket with an attachment via any version of REST API. What we do is creating a ticket and then put there an attachment as comment. It's not nice but working.

Comment: @Houmles Thanks a lot for your reply! I wonder if you could post an answer showing the Java code in order to achieve that...

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot test your code, I suggest you to use HttpClient 4, I provide below a sample code snippet. Modify the code as per your requirement and try to check.

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://rtserver.com");
FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file, ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY);
StringBody stringBody1 = new StringBody("Message 1", ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
builder.addPart("upfile", fileBody);
builder.addPart("text1", stringBody1);

HttpEntity entity = builder.build();

post.setEntity(entity);

HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```